# Using Text qualifier in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file having ^ as the text qualifier and , as delimiter. I can read it in MS access but unable to do so in pandas/python.

What is the option to provide text qualifier in pandas read_csv?

```
col_list=pd.read_csv("abc.csv",nrows=1,sep=',').columns.tolist()

['^Run_Time^',
 '^Run_Desc^',
 '^As_Of_Date^']
```

Comment: `quotechar='^'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.read_csv("abc.csv",quotechar='^',nrows=1, sep=',')`