# Adding Text qualifying while using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

So what I'm trying to do is add text qualifiers to my whole CSV. What I'm expecting is for each value to be wrapped in double quotes "" however this does not seem to be the case?

Does anyone know if I'll be able to add any Text Qualifying when creating a csv or is there a better solution for what im trying to do?

```
df.to_csv('Clean_zenos_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), index=False, quotechar='"', sep=',')
```

Comment: Pls add more detail to the question.  What exactly are you trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: More information has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that this is possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122750/using-text-qualifier-in-pandas), and the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/io.html#io-store-in-csv) also provides a certain approach for doing so. I've tried your code and I can verify it works.

Comment: Looks like you unnacepted this answer. Is there something wrong? I'd like to help you.

Comment: So reading the documentation provided and checking the solution here this did not add and text qualifier's to my final CSV? I have added my output in the original question. Using quotechar='"' i expected a Double quote to be added to every output in the CSV.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Checking this out right now and editing the comment.